# The installed Boto library must be 2.4 or higher error when using django-storages on ec2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm trying to connect to Amazon s3 from a Django application running on Amazon ec2 to upload and serve media files. I'm using [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/) to connect to s3 via the python boto library.

I can get this to work on my local machine using the django built in web server without a problem but when I deploy the project on Amazon ec2 I get the following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured
The installed Boto library must be 2.4 or higher.
See https://github.com/boto/boto
```

I'm running my application in a virtual environment and I have confirmed that the version of boto installed is 2.9. I've confirmed that this is the version that django is accessing by running

```
python manage.py shell
```

and importing boto then printing the version.

Here is the relevant snippet of my settings.py:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: After commenting out the lines in the django-storages code that checks the version and throws an error if less than 2.4, I was able to get things working again. I'm assuming this is an issue with django-storages and I will post an issue there.

Comment: I had the same problem, but in my case it was caused by system wide boto library being picked up first before one from virtualenv.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Also, I am not able to comment if condition which checks for version.